# Getting gmap-vue in a nuxt project to work

Tags: google-maps

I want to make use of [gmap-vue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gmap-vue) in a nuxt project. I am confused by

> In your main.js or inside a Nuxt plugin:

as I don't have main.js and also don't have any plugins.

However I have tried by creating a new plugin file called gmap.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import * as GmapVue from 'gmap-vue'

Vue.use(GmapVue, {
    load: {
        key: process.env.gMapKey,
    },
    installComponents: true
})
```

and then add into nuxtcongif.js

```
plugins: [
    '~/plugins/gmap.js'
],
```

but I get the error in the browser:

```
SyntaxError Unexpected token '<'
```

and in gmap.js it does not recgonise the module:

[image]

Any pointers to get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

Change this line

```
import * as GmapVue from 'gmap-vue';
```

to this (see gmap-vue documentation for [Nuxt.js config](https://diegoazh.github.io/gmap-vue/#nuxt-js-config))

```
import * as GmapVue from '~/node_modules/gmap-vue';
```

Answer (score 1):

For `Nuxt.js` app add the following option to your `nuxt.config.js's build.extend()`:

```
build: {
    transpile: [/^gmap-vue($|\/)/]
}
```

Similar to [`vue2-google-maps` Nuxt.js config](https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps#nuxtjs-config) which `gmap-vue` is a fork of.

Comment: Thanks - but this does not fix the problem. It still says it does not recgonise the module.

Comment: It is the strangest thing but it is finally working with the error (Could not find a declaration file for module 'gmap-vue') still there. Will have to live with that. Thanks for your help.